# Prefetch with few filters for one related model

Tags: django, django-orm

There is a table `Order`, which is connected to table `Signal` through `FK`. I loop through the records from table `Signal` and access the child elements from table `Order`. As a result, I get `N+1 query`. Tried to do `prefetch_related`, `Prefetch`, but nothing helps.

```py
for profile in Profile.objects.all():
    for signal in profile.signals.prefetch_related("orders").all():
        filter1 = signal.orders.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER).order_by("exchanged_at")
        filter2 = signal.orders.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER)
        filter3 = signal.orders.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.EXIT)
        filter4 = signal.orders.filter(exchanged_at__isnull=False)
        print(filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4)
```

**models.py**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...


class Signal(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="signals", ...)


class Order(models.Model):
    signal = models.ForeignKey(Signal, related_name="orders", ...)
    position_direction = models.CharField(...)
    exchanged_at = models.BooleanField(...)
```

Comment: Please add your `models.py`

Comment: Each of the `filter1`, `filter2`, ...,  lines will create a new query which is not using the prefetch, as you are adding new conditions/filter expressions.

Comment: Please describe qhat you are trying to get as a result, as your code is just executin some "random" queries.

Comment: @JanMalte I just gave a minimally reproducible example with a problem so as not to lay out the whole sheet of code.

Comment: so whats the issue? you didnt make it clear

Comment: @Walucas The problem is that at each iteration in the loop, a request is made to each of the filters

Comment: Is there a way to do this all in one request?

Comment: so all you want is a list of Orders that the profile made through signals?

Comment: @Walucas I need 4 different querysets of orders for a certain filter for each signal (which I iterate over in a loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) objects to add additional attributes to the returned instances that contained custom prefetched querysets by passing the `to_attr` argument

```
for signal in profile.signals.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('orders', queryset=Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER).order_by("exchanged_at"), to_attr='filter1'),
    Prefetch('orders', queryset=Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER), to_attr='filter2'),
    Prefetch('orders', queryset=Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.EXIT), to_attr='filter3'),
    Prefetch('orders', queryset=Order.objects.filter(exchanged_at__isnull=False), to_attr='filter4'),
).all():
    filter1 = signal.filter1
    filter2 = signal.filter2
    filter3 = signal.filter3
    filter4 = signal.filter4
    print(filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4)
```

Comment: It's nice. But I can't `aggregate` this? (`filter3` f.e.)

Comment: What do you mean by "aggregate this", can you give an example? Custom prefetch attributes can'y be used further on in the query if that's what you mean

Comment: f.e. `filter1.aggregate(filled=Coalesce(Sum("filled"), 0, output_field=DecimalField()))["filled"]`

Comment: The prefetched attributes are lists not querysets so you won't be able to call queryset methods on them. If you could call `aggregate` then you would again be running a query per object, I thought you were trying to reduce the number of queries? Is your original question resolved by this answer?

Comment: Thnx for help. Also I can use _nested_ `Prefetch` into `Profile.objects` for fix N+1  query on the `signals` table

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of orders based on the profile Signals:

```
signals_ids = profile.signals.values_list('id',flat=True)
profile_orders = Order.objects.filter(id__in=signals_ids)
```

Then you apply the other filters on the `profile_orders` variable

`profile_orders = profile_orders.filter(...)`

Comment: I tried this and saw database queries for `each new filter`, on each iteration(

Comment: So you want just 1 query to do it all?

Comment: I want to decrease queries to db

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your algorithm exists a logical mistake.
For example: filter1, filter2, filter3 are querysets and filter4 is object
But you still can create Prefetch:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch

```
for signal in profile.signals.prefetch_related(
  Prefetch('filter1', queryset=Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER).order_by("exchanged_at")),
  Prefetch('filter2', queryset=Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.ENTER)),
  Prefetch('filte3', queryset= Order.objects.filter(position_direction=OrderDirectionChoice.EXIT)),
  Prefetch('filter4',queryset= Order.objects.filter(exchanged_at__isnull=False)[:1])).all():
    print(signal.filter1.all(), signal.filter2.all(), signal.filter3.all(), signal.filter4.all())
```

Comment: ahaha the same answer as Iain Shelvington

Comment: When using to_attr the prefetched result is stored in a list, not querysets